# How many coefficients are needed to reconstruct exactly vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

1. How many coefficients are needed to reconstruct exactly vectors (a) $S(\{2,4,6\}) \subset l^2(\mathbb{Z}^9)$ and (b) in $S(\{1,3,4\}) \subset l^2(\mathbb{Z}^{12})$?
2. Find the missing coefficients $x$ and $y$ of the vector
   $v=(1,1,x,0,1,y,0,0,0) \in S(\{2,4,6\})$.

**How many coefficients are needed to reconstruct exactly vectors ...**

How do I do this part?

**Find the missing coefficients $x$ and $y$ of the vector $v=(1,1,x,0,1,y,0,0,0) \in S(\{2,4,6\})$.**

Define $v=\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1\\ x\\ 0\\ 1\\ y\\ 0\\ 0\\ 0\\ \end{bmatrix}$ and $w=\begin{bmatrix} 1\\ 1\\ 1\\  1\\ 1\\ 1\\  1\\ 1\\ 1\\ \end{bmatrix}$ where $\|v\|=1$ and $x,y \geq 0$. $$\sum_{k=0}^8 |v[k]|=2+x+1+y=3+x+y \iff \langle v,w \rangle=\sum_{k=0}^8|v[k]|\bar{1}$$ bY Cauchy-Schwarz, $3+x+y=|\langle v,w \rangle| \leq \|v\| \cdot \|w\|=\sqrt{9}$. However, since we know that v is $0$ in four of its coordinates, we can get a much better estimate again using Cauchy-Schwarz, where this time we estimate the inner product of $v$ with the vector $\tilde{w}=\begin{bmatrix} 1\\ 1\\ 1\\ 0\\ 1\\ 1\\ 0\\ 0\\ 0\\ \end{bmatrix}$ $$x+y+3=|\langle v,w \rangle| \leq \|v\| \cdot \|w\|=\sqrt{5}$$ So $x=y=1$.

edit: Correct answer for number 2. By definition, $$S(\{2,4,6\})=\{ v \in \mathbb{C}^9: \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & \alpha_2 & 0 & \alpha_4 & 0 \alpha_6 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}^T \}.$$ So we can see that no matter what $x$ and $y$ are the vector $v$ isn't in $S(\{2,4,6\})$.

Comment: What does $S(\{2,4,6\})$ mean?

Comment: Let $F=\{1,3,4\}$ in $l^2(\mathbb{Z}^9)$. $S(F)=\{ v \in \mathbb{C}^n: \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ \alpha_1 \\ 0 \\ \alpha_3 \\ \alpha_4 \\ 0 \\ \cdot \\ \cdot \\ \cdot \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: If that's accurate, then in your problem $2$, $v$ cannot possibly be in $S(\{2,4,6\})$ no matter what values you give to $x$ and $y$.

Comment: What is part 1 asking from me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\textbf{How many coefficients are needed to reconstruct exactly vectors $\dots$}$

Note we can use Thm 9.14 to find enough coefficients to reconstruct unique vectors i.e. $$|T|>N-2\sqrt{N}+|F|$$

$\textbf{Part a:}$
Let $N=9$ and $|F|=3$. So $|T|>9-6+3=6$. So 6 non-zero coefficients are necessary.

$\textbf{Part b:}$
Let $N=12$ and $|F|=3$. So $|T|>12-4\sqrt{3}+3=8.1$. So 9 non-zero coefficients are necessary.

$\textbf{Find the missing coefficients $x$ and $y$ of the vector $v \in S(\{2,4,6\})$}$

By definition, $$S(\{2,4,6\})=\{ v \in \mathbb{C}^9: \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & \alpha_2 & 0 & \alpha_4 & 0 \alpha_6 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}^T \}.$$ So we can see that no matter what $x$ and $y$ are the vector $v$ isn't in $S(\{2,4,6\})$.